# Errors while building Cuba lib file C++

Tags: c++, build-error

I tried using the Cuba library and tried building the Cuba lib file using the following commands:

```
./configure
make
```

The first command worked successfully but the `make` command generated the following error at the end:

```
.....
gcc -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -ffast-math -Wall -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DREALSIZE=8 -I./src/common -I. -I. -I./src/cuhre -DLONGLONGINT -c -o llCuhre_.o ./src/cuhre/Cuhre.c
ar rv libcuba.a llCuhre_.o
a - llCuhre_.o
rm -f llCuhre_.o
gcc -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -ffast-math -Wall -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DREALSIZE=8 -I./src/common -I. -I. -DNOUNDERSCORE -c -o Fork.o ./src/common/Fork.c
In file included from ./src/common/Fork.c:11:0:
./src/common/Fork.c: In function 'cubawait':
./src/common/stddecl.h:193:29: error: 'cubafun_' undeclared (first use in this function)
 #define MasterExit() do if( cubafun_.init ) { \
                             ^
./src/common/Fork.c:160:3: note: in expansion of macro 'MasterExit'
   MasterExit();
   ^~~~~~~~~~
./src/common/stddecl.h:193:29: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
 #define MasterExit() do if( cubafun_.init ) { \
                             ^
./src/common/Fork.c:160:3: note: in expansion of macro 'MasterExit'
   MasterExit();
   ^~~~~~~~~~
makefile:254: recipe for target 'libcuba.a(Fork.o)' failed
make: *** [libcuba.a(Fork.o)] Error 1
```

I don't understand what the problem is and how can it be fixed so that `libcuba.a` file is generated at the end? If anyone has a solution, please let me know about it.

Comment: Looking at the source, it seems like a bug to me. But (probably) it is also a misconfiguration of your build. How experienced are you at building this kind of software?

Comment: you could try to open an issue on the [Github repository](https://github.com/JohannesBuchner/cuba)

Comment: @john not very experienced... but i followed all the steps available in the documentation

Comment: https://github.com/JohannesBuchner/cuba This is the link to the library. I'm working on Windows using MinGW. If you could download the repo and try it for yourself, that would be a great help

Comment: @PrashannaM.Paudel OK that makes sense of your situation. The code you are compiling uses *conditional compilation*, so for some people one piece of code gets compiled but for others different code gets compiled. One of the conditions that matters is whether a function called `fork` is available. This is available on Linux, but it is not on Windows when using MinGW. So you are compiling the 'no fork available' version of the code. It's this part of the code that has the problem that you have found.

Comment: @PrashannaM.Paudel I notice from this [page](http://www.feynarts.de/cuba/) that Windows is supported when using [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/). Cygwin is another Linux like subsystem for Windows, it's a bit more comprehensive than MinGW. And interestingly Cygwin does support the `fork` function. So I guess your best bet would be to forget about MinGW and instead try to get this library compiled using Cygwin.

Comment: @john Thank you so much. Cygwin works perfectly without any error.